# WordPress - bbPress full width issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, bbpress

I am having issues with getting the bbPress plugin full width, - if I create a new page called 'forum' or 'forums', and put the [bbp-forum-index] shortcode in on that page, and make the page setting full width no sidebar it seems to work.

Now, when I click on the forum category itself, it makes the forum then go to the left side, roughly 60% of page, leaving the right side untouched with no sidebar.

I've tried **width; 100%;** under .bbpress-forums, didn't work.
I've tried creating a new bbPress.php page, with the full width page template code in it, it also didn't work.

Picture of my issue;
https://image.prntscr.com/image/MlelT-DGSpSlLet6tBTTkw.png

I apologize if my question isn't clear, or if I'm missing something so simple, just can't wrap my head around this... Note that I don't know a whole lot about code but I know a little bit.

If it's any help, I am using;
bbPress v2.15.4
and Socialize by GhostPool as the theme.

**EDIT:** I've gotten half way! I've set "no sidebar" as the default option... now this is where I am stuck! https://image.prntscr.com/image/HONffga5SYq3DA6wi_CcxA.png

Answer (score -1):

Can you provide the link to the website? As far as I can see on website for Socialize: Multi-Purpose BuddyPress Theme author sad that that he provided large, full-width and full page theme. Maybe you missed some option or just need some CSS tweak.